# Is God from Supernatural immortal post season 10?

Tags: supernatural

If, as Death states, that Death will be the one to reap God, then why was God on the verge of dying at the end of season 11? The process of him dying doesn't make sense if it seemed to be implied that Death would be the one to reap him. Death's death in season 10 just seems to create a lot of complicated paradoxes in the series.

Comment: Death's comment was merely saying that he (in his mind) was going to outlive God. Doesn't mean he was right.

Comment: @KutuluMike - Alternately, the writers have no idea where things are going and don't like anything Dean can't stab to death.

Comment: I haven't watched season 11 yet, but Sam & Dean already gave one "eternal prophecy" the boot when Michael and Lucifer tried to possess them to enact the apocalypse (season 5-ish?)  Clearly, just because eternal beings have been saying "Death will be the one to reap God" since the **literal beginning of time** doesn't actually mean it's going to happen.  Dean (or was it Sam?) killing Death was just another kick in the crotch for anyone foolish enough to bank on prophecy in this series.

Answer (score 1):

1. Death still exists in supernatural world even if there is no more rider of death. It exists as a fact and not as a person.
   So god was truly dying
2. God was reaped something more powerful than death-Darkness
   It seems that power ladder in supernatural is

   1. Darkness
   2. God
   3. Death